# Como programar acciones automaticas

Tags: django

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion la cual un usuario se le asigna un proceso de construccion y tiene una fecha de inicio de la obra como una fecha fin, este es el modelo Obra:

```
class Obra(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=timezone.now())
    end_date = models.DateField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=timezone.now())
```

Lo que quiero realizar es que cuando la fecha inicio sea igual a la fecha fin se realize una accion en la base de datos, lo probe con un signal de user_logged_in:

```
@receiver(user_logged_in, sender=User)
def set_update_date(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    for project in projects:
        hoy = timezone.now()
        if hoy >= project.end_date:
            project.status = False
        else:
            project.status = True
```

Cada vez que el usuario inicia sesión el signar se activa y verifica la fecha de hoy con la fecha del modelo Obra si la fecha de hoy es igual o mayor a la de fin, se realizara un proceso en la base de datos, pero el problema es que esto solo se hará cuando un usuario inicie sesión

Comment: De que tratan las fechas "inicio" y "fin"? De inicio y cierre de sesión del usuario? si es así, las señales [`user_logged_in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_in) y [`user_logged_out`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_out) son exactamente las que necesitas...

Comment: no, es de un modelo diferente pero uso el signal user_logged_in, para que cuando el usuario inicie sesion se hagan las verificaciones de las fechas sean iguales

Comment: Entonces actualiza tu pregunta explicando **exactamente que quieres hacer**, el problema, que es lo que has intentado, etc, (y adjunta los modelos obviamente) para así ayudarte mas fácilmente, ya que es muy poca la información que nos brindas.

Comment: ya hice la edicion podria verificar por favor

Comment: Entonces necesitas la "verificación" cada cierto tiempo de manera permanente verdad?

Comment: asi es pero no se realmente como hacerlo

Comment: no se la manera mas optima

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118134/discussion-between-julio-cesar-and-cosmos-multi).